# How to check if an Airflow user already exists in the airflow DB in Python code

Tags: python, airflow, basic-authentication, createuser

I am new to airflow and got a task to add basic auth for Airflow Webserver. I implemented that using the below python code(from https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/security.html#password). I was able to create a user and authenticate to Airflow Webserver using that user/password.

```
# navigate to the airflow installation directory
$ cd ~/airflow
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 10 2015, 03:28:08)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import airflow
>>> from airflow import models, settings
>>> from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
>>> user = PasswordUser(models.User())
>>> user.username = 'new_user_name'
>>> user.email = 'new_user_email@example.com'
>>> user.password = 'set_the_password'
>>> session = settings.Session()
>>> session.add(user)
>>> session.commit()
>>> session.close()
>>> exit()
```

However, now I need to make sure that I only update the user instead of creating if the user already exists in airflow DB.
Is there an attribute for the `session` object like `get` or `getusers` to know if the user already exists.

I am able to see the user created in airflowdb.users table in the database. But, I need to check from Python code instead.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`session` is an instance of the [SQLAlchemy Session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session.html). Its `execute()` method allows you to run SQL expressions. So, you can simply select from the users table:

```
from airflow import settings
session = settings.Session()
users = session.execute("SELECT * FROM users").fetchall()
print(users)
session.close()
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'new_user_name', 'new_user_email@example.com', '$2b$12$qr7bCywAv4kTeakli.fTXuNUXonqSzXUqZIX/ZVIMceZDEIsKhgNO', 0)]
```

Comment: RemovedIn20Warning: